# Can't send customMetrics and customEvents data to Application insights

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

Application telemetry is my new area. I can't send my custom data to Application insights to query and monitor.
I need to send an user ID metrics to application insights who access my web-application written in .NET Core MVC model.
I've added a code after referencing from articles out there and from official documentation, once I add these custom Code under my controller the default data that used to send to insights is stopped

I've tried added the following code under a controller. NOTE: This is for testing whether I can able to send metrics of my own. I too added some static data to test.

I've passed the TelemetryClient by DI method

```
        try
        {
            // Track a custom metric
            telemetryClient.GetMetric("CustomMetricID").TrackValue(userid);
            telemetryClient.GetMetric("TestMetric").TrackValue(1);
            // Set the user and organization IDs
            telemetryClient.Context.User.Id = userid.ToString();

           // Track a custom event
            var customEvent = new EventTelemetry("CustomEvent_UserID");
            customEvent.Properties.Add("Int_USER_ID", userid.ToString());
            customEvent.Properties.Add("Desc", "Working...");
            telemetryClient.TrackEvent(customEvent);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            telemetryClient.TrackException(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            telemetryClient.Flush();
        }
```

I'm expecting to send my custom data (here USER_ID) to application insights.

Comment: can you check what you're getting in Fiddler to exclude cases when you're not seeing data for some unrelated reason (incorrect endpoint, wrong instrumentation key, etc.)?

Comment: Please paste code as formatted text, not as an image.

Comment: Does your `Program.cs` has `builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();`.

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: Then how do you get an instance of TelemetryClient and how is it configured? I understand you get it using DI but I wonder how it is made available in de DI container.

Comment: Also, you mentioned docs and reference articles you used to get started, can you provide links to them?

Comment: Yes, Sure. Here it is, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics#trackevent ; https://youtu.be/jhepPNaaiyw ; https://youtu.be/iTRILNstmFI

Comment: I've tried, (for testing if it's working or not) using the following code `telemetry.TrackEvent("Working...");` and received the following message as **TRACE** _AI: TelemetryChannel found a telemetry item without an InstrumentationKey. This is a required field and must be set in either your config file or at application startup._

Comment: @VikramR - Please share your `appsettings.json` file. You nee to add `ApplicationInsights` - `InstrumentationKey` in the `appsettings.json` file.

Comment: @Harshitha Thank you!. I've missed that instrumentation key part. Instead of sending the DI, I've used a new instance which bypasses the DI system. The application now sends the data after fixing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> TelemetryChannel found a telemetry item without an InstrumentationKey. This is a required field and must be set in either your config file or at application startup_

- The code which you have configured is correct.
- We need to add the Application Insights `ConnectionString/InstrumentationKey` in the `appsettings.json` file.

[image]

`appsettings.json`

```cs
{
  "Logging": {
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug",
        "Microsoft": "Error"
      }
    },
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApplicationInsights": {   
  "ConnectionString": "InstrumentationKey=56**9q4-****-4**9-8a4f-a******d6a;IngestionEndpoint=https://eastus-8.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://eastus.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/"
  }
}
```

Install the NuGet package `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore`.

***`.csproj`  file:***

```cs
<PackageReference  Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore"  Version="2.21.0" />
```

- Add the below line in `Pogram.cs` file.

```cs
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
```

- Make sure `TelemetryClient` is configured correctly with the `InstrumentationKey`.
- In Controller create an Instance of `TelemetryClient` .

> ```cs
>  public readonly TelemetryClient mytelemetry;
> ```

***OR***

> ```cs
> public TelemetryClient mytelemetry = new TelemetryClient();
> ```

```cs
public MyController(TelemetryClient telemetryClient) 
{
   mytelemetry= telemetryClient; 
}
```